# Singly linked list - Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

First, sorry for the long code. I did my best to trim it as small as possible.
I'm getting segmentation fault when i want to add a new element (`void SLList::pushBack(const Data &rDATA)`) to my singly linked list (in SLList.hxx). The segmentation fault caused by 0xbaadf00d value.
........................................................................................................

IniFile.h

```
#include "Section.h"
class IniFile
{
  public:
    IniFile() :
    void addSection();

  private:
    SLList<Section> mContent;
};
```

IniFile.cpp

```
#include "IniFile.h"
IniFile::IniFile() :
   mContent() {}

void IniFile::addSection() // This is the only one method what i call
{
   mContent.pushBack(Section());
}
```

Section.h

```
#include "Pair.hxx"
#include "SLList.hxx"
class Section
{
  public:
    Section();

  private:
    SLList<Pair<std::string, std::string>> mKeyValuePairs;
};
```

Section.cpp

```
#include "Section.h"
Section::Section() :
    mKeyValuePairs() {}
```

SLList.hxx

```
template <typename Data>
class SLList
{
  public:
    class Node
    {
      public:
        Node(const Data &rDATA, Node *const pNEXT = nullptr) :
            mData(rDATA),
            mNext(pNEXT) {}

        Node(const Node &rRHS)
        {
            mData = rRHS.mData;
            *mNext = *rRHS.mNext;
        }

        ~Node()
        {
            delete mNext;
        }

        Node &operator=(const Node &rRHS)
        {
            if (&rRHS == this)
                return *this;
            mData = rRHS.mData;
            *mNext = *rRHS.mNext;
            return *this;
        }

      private:
        void setNext(Node *const pNext)
        {
            mNext = pNext;
        }

        friend void SLList<Data>::pushBack(const Data &rDATA);

      private:
        Data mData;
        Node *mNext;
    };

    SLList() :
        mHead(nullptr),
        mTail(nullptr) {}


    SLList(const SLList &rRHS)
    {
        *mHead = *rRHS.mHead;
        *mTail = *rRHS.mTail;
    }

    SLList &operator=(const SLList &rRHS)
    {
        if (&rRHS == this)
            return *this;
        *mHead = *rRHS.mHead;
        *mTail = *rRHS.mTail;
        return *this;
    }

    ~SLList()
    {
        clear();
    }

    void clear()
    {
        delete mHead;
    }

    void pushBack(const Data &rDATA)
    {
        Node *pNode = new Node(rDATA, nullptr); // I get segmentation fault at this point
        if (!mTail)
        {
            mHead = pNode;
            mTail = pNode;
        }
        else
        {
            mTail->setNext(pNode);
            mTail = pNode;
        }
    }

  private:
    Node *mHead;
    Node *mTail;
};
```

Pair.hxx

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Pair
{
  public:
    Pair(const T1 &rFIRST, const T2 &rSECOND) :
        mFirst(rFIRST),
        mSecond(rSECOND) {}

  private:
    T1 mFirst;
    T2 mSecond;
};
```

Comment: did you run your code in a debugger? 0xbaadf00d is used by Microsoft to indicate uninitialised heap memory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, i did, but i can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: where did it crash? what functions of your class are you calling and with what parameters?

Comment: @AlanBirtles It crashes when i call `SLList<Section>::pushBack(Section())` method. `Section` is a class which has a `SLList<Pair<std::string, std::string>>` member, and `Pair` is a template class, like `std::pair`

Comment: the bug could be anywhere in your code, its difficult to help without the complete code

Comment: The code is not so small. Where should i paste it?

Comment: Trim your code down to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this will likely also help you narrow down the bug by reducing the amount of extraneous code involved.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your suggestions. I'm making a test, and unfortunately i can't use STL. Can you show me (in code) what you wrote about, because i don't understand exactly?!

Comment: @Dean see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SLList`'s copy constructor and assignment operator are wrong in terms of `Node*` pointer management.

Also, `Node`'s destructor shouldn't destroy the next `Node` object in the list. Not only is a recursive destructor bad for long lists, but also think of in the future if you ever want to remove a single `Node` without clearing the whole list.  Your `clear()` method should directly iterate the list deleting `Node` objects one at a time without using recursion.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <utility>
template <typename Data>
class SLList
{
public:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node(const Data &rDATA, Node *const pNEXT = nullptr)
            : mData(rDATA), mNext(pNEXT)
        {
        }

        Node(const Node &rSRC)
            : mData(rSRC.mData), mNext(nullptr)
        {
        }

        Node &operator=(const Node &rRHS)
        {
            if (&rRHS != this)
                mData = rRHS.mData;
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        Data mData;
        Node *mNext;

        friend class SLList<Data>;
    };

    SLList()
        : mHead(nullptr), mTail(nullptr)
    {
    }

    SLList(const SLList &rSRC)
        : mHead(nullptr), mTail(nullptr)
    {
        Node *pNode = rSRC.mHead;
        while (pNode)
        {
            pushBack(pNode->mData);
            pNode = pNode->mNext;
        } 
    }

    SLList &operator=(const SLList &rRHS)
    {
        if (&rRHS != this)
        {
            SLList temp(rRHS);
            std::swap(mHead, temp.mHead);
            std::swap(mTail, temp.mTail);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~SLList()
    {
        clear();
    }

    void clear()
    {
        Node *pNode = mHead;
        mHead = mTail = nullptr;
        while (pNode)
        {
            Node *pNext = pNode->mNext;
            delete pNode;
            pNode = pNext;
        }
    }

    void pushBack(const Data &rDATA)
    {
        Node *pNode = new Node(rDATA);
        if (!mHead) mHead = pNode;
        if (mTail) mTail->mNext = pNode;
        mTail = pNode;
    }

private:
    Node *mHead;
    Node *mTail;
};
```

With that said, what you *really* should do is use `std::list` (or `std::forward_list`) and `std::pair` instead. There is no benefit to "reinventing the wheel" at all:

```
#include "Section.h"
#include <list>
class IniFile
{
public:
    void addSection();
private:
    std::list<Section> mContent;
};
```

```
#include "IniFile.h"
void IniFile::addSection()
{
    mContent.push_back(Section());
}
```

```
#include <pair>
#include <list>
#include <string>
class Section
{
private:
    std::list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> mKeyValuePairs;
};
```

```
#include <list>
template <typename Data>
class SLList
{
public:
    void clear()
    {
        mList.clear();
    }

    void pushBack(const Data &rDATA)
    {
        mList.push_back(rDATA);
    }

private:
    std::list<Data> mList;
};
```